# how to create json file using powershell from another json file

Tags: json, powershell

I want to fetch values from one json and pass to another json. I wan only few parameters into it like name,severity,range ,cwe,cvssand fixAvailable. this is my json file:

```
{
  "auditReportVersion": 2,
  "vulnerabilities": {
    "@babel/traverse": {
      "name": "@babel/traverse",
      "severity": "critical",
      "isDirect": false,
      "via": [
        {
          "source": 1094446,
          "name": "@babel/traverse",
          "dependency": "@babel/traverse",
          "title": "Babel vulnerable to arbitrary code execution when compiling specifically crafted malicious code",
          "url": "https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-67hx-6x53-jw92",
          "severity": "critical",
          "cwe": [
            "CWE-184",
            "CWE-697"
          ],
          "cvss": {
            "score": 9.3,
            "vectorString": "CVSS:3.1/AV:L/AC:L/PR:N/UI:N/S:C/C:H/I:H/A:H"
          },
          "range": "<7.23.2"
        }
      ],
      "effects": [],
      "range": "<7.23.2",
      "nodes": [
        "node_modules/@babel/traverse"
      ],
      "fixAvailable": true
    }
}}
```

I want file like this:

```
{
  "auditReportVersion": 2,
  "vulnerabilities": {
    "@babel/traverse": {
      "name": "@babel/traverse",
      "severity": "critical",
      "range": "\<7.23.2",
      "fixAvailable": true
}
}
}
```

Need help.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one of the ways you can do it, convert the JSON input to an object using `ConvertFrom-JSON` cmdlet and then you create a custom object with the desired attribute setup, and if you want that in JSON you can use `$obj | ConvertTo-JSON` cmdlet.

```
$jsonInput=@"
{
    "auditReportVersion": 2,
    "vulnerabilities": {
        "@babel/traverse": {
            "name": "@babel/traverse",
            "severity": "critical",
            "isDirect": false,
            "via": [
                {
                    "source": 1094446,
                    "name": "@babel/traverse",
                    "dependency": "@babel/traverse",
                    "title": "Babel vulnerable to arbitrary code execution when compiling specifically crafted malicious code",
                    "url": "https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-67hx-6x53-jw92",
                    "severity": "critical",
                    "cwe": [
                        "CWE-184",
                        "CWE-697"
                    ],
                    "cvss": {
                        "score": 9.3,
                        "vectorString": "CVSS:3.1/AV:L/AC:L/PR:N/UI:N/S:C/C:H/I:H/A:H"
                    },
                    "range": "<7.23.2"
                }
            ],
            "effects": [],
            "range": "<7.23.2",
            "nodes": [
                "node_modules/@babel/traverse"
            ],
            "fixAvailable": true
        }
    }
}
"@

$inputObj = $jsonInput | ConvertFrom-Json

$obj = [pscustomobject]@{
    auditReportVersion = $inputObj.auditReportVersion
    vulnerabilities = [pscustomobject]@{
        '@babel/traverse' = [pscustomobject]@{
            name = $inputObj.vulnerabilities.'@babel/traverse'.name
            severity = $inputObj.vulnerabilities.'@babel/traverse'.severity
            range = $inputObj.vulnerabilities.'@babel/traverse'.range
            fixAvailable = $inputObj.vulnerabilities.'@babel/traverse'.fixAvailable
        }
    }
}


$obj | ConvertTo-Json
```